# НА парте или ЗА партой?

Tags: употребление-слов

Часто можно услышать оба варианта. Но какое более правильное? Или они равнозначны?

Мне кажется, что ЗА лучше, т.к. "сидеть НА второй парте" - можно понять и как "сидеть сверху на самой столешнице" (на рабочей поверхности). Хотя если вспомнить те парты, которые были раньше - с длинной скамейкой, приделанной к столу, то вся эта конструкция называлась партой. На ней можно было сидеть, подразумевая под "партой" и скамейку для нее.  Сейчас редко, но можно встретить похожие модели парт.

Хотелось бы услышать ваши мнения. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"За партой", конечно. "На" — это уже какое-то разговорно-просторечное. Нет, конечно, детишки на партах тоже любят посидеть на переменах, но на уроках они все-таки сидят ЗА партами)))

Comment: И я так считала, но вчера читала детям "Старика Хоттабыча". В тексте не один раз встречается "на парте" в значении "за партой"...

Comment: Да и в реальной жизни ребята (да и учителя!) часто говорят "на парте", например:  "сидит на последней парте". Но все-таки, соглашусь с Fuchoin Kazuki, это разговорный вариант, особенно применимо к современным партам. А вот во времена "Хоттабыча" парты были другие, тут Вы правы. Стол и скамья составляли единое целое. Может, тогда было правильным "Сидеть на..."? Потом парты изменились, а выражение осталось?

Comment: Согласен  с  Ларf.

Comment: Настоящие парты были ещё у меня в школе (закончил шесть лет назад), причём довольно новые.

Answer (score 3):

Ну да. На партах могли сидеть только гимназисты, некоторые студенты и иногда школьники начальных классов. Те, у кого них парта представляла собой именно парту. Скамейку со столиком специалной конструкции. Вот ЗА этой партой-столом они и сидят НА парте-скамейке.

Но мне кажется, выражение НА парте не с этим связано. Работать на швейной машинке, на станке, на автобусе, сидеть на телефоне - не прямо же на них?

А может быть на последнюю парту - это направление? Как на Камчатку.

Comment: Согласен с тем, что это больше похоже на направление. Обычно если употребляют с предлогом "на", то в контексте "Садись/иди на первую/последнюю парту" или "Я сижу на первой/последней парте". Предлог "на" здесь переносит смысловое ударение на удалённость, а не сам факт нахождения за партой. К тому же, если сказать, что человек сидит ЗА последней партой, то возникает некоторая двусмысленность: то ли речь о последней парте, то ли ученику стул в самом конце класса поставили, на котором он сидит позади всех.

Answer (score 1):

Парта есть вид мебели, где наклон. стол един с сиденьем. Сидят НА такой парте: на третьей парте от окна.
Если это стол(ик) и стул, то сидеть на стуле за столом. Неправильно называть эту пару партой.